# Gravity Forms: Embedding via do_shortcode resulting in "Notifications" text appearing from wp_footer

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Latest Wordpress install with Gravity Forms (ver 2.6.9).

Using a ACF field to enter in the shortcode for a Gravity Form. On the template side using echo do_shortcode to get the corresponding Gravity Form.

The actual form appears correctly, but on any page showing a form, I get "

Notification

" outputted from wp_footer.

[image: inspection of code highlighting the resulting output that is of issue]

Tested removing the wp_footer from the theme and it is definitely appearing as a result of that call, and it only appears on pages where a gravity form is present.

Tried the following, nothing fixed it thus far:

- Toggled no Conflict Mode off
- Toggled Output HTML5 off
- Toggled Legacy Markup on
- Appears whether logged in or not.